# Camel rest JSON deserialize with START_ARRAY

Tags: apache-camel

I'm try to convert a `application/json` from rest service to a list of POJO. 
But I can't

My input is a list of `Event` in `camel:put` I cannot refer a list.

```
<dataFormats>
  <json id="eventJsonList" prettyPrint="true" library="Jackson" useList="true"
    unmarshalTypeName="example.model.Event" />
</dataFormats>

<camel:rest path="events" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
  <camel:put 
    uri="/save">
    <to uri="direct:save-events" />
  </camel:put>
</camel:rest>
```

using `Camel 2.22`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `camel:unmarshall` to tell the route to use your data format.

```
<camel:rest path="events" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
    <camel:put uri="/save">
        <camel:route>
            <camel:unmarshal ref="eventJsonList" />
            <camel:to uri="direct:save-events" />
        </camel:route>
    </camel:put>
</camel:rest>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the `camel:rest` have `bindingMode` is `auto` as default. property. Must be disabled  `bindingMode="off"`

Comment: @AlissonGomes works fine for me without having to disable bindingMode or convert body to string. I'm using camel 2.22.2. Good to see you got it working though.

Comment: Good, thank you for your feedback. I didn't try with `<camel:route>` nested to `camel:put`. Could be this.

Answer (score 0):

Property `bindingMode="off"` must be disabled and the body converted to String:

```
<dataFormats>
  <json id="eventJsonList" prettyPrint="true" library="Jackson" useList="true"
    unmarshalTypeName="example.model.Event" />
</dataFormats>

<camel:rest path="events" bindingMode="off" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
  <camel:put 
    uri="/save">
    <to uri="direct:save-events" />
  </camel:put>
</camel:rest>

<camel:route  id="save-events">
  <from uri="direct:save-events" />
  <camel:convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
  <camel:unmarshal ref="eventJsonList"/>
  <to uri="mock:result"/>
</camel:route>
```